# Is using stringbuilder to output HTML for a database report okay?

Tags: c#, sql, reporting

I have a very simple application that handles product orders.

I want to do some reporting like a daily sales report.

So here is my idea:

Id like to build an attractive HTML page, and then copy/paste each HTML line into code like

```
Stringbuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); 
sb.AppendLine("<html><body>"); // each HTML line here
sb.AppendLine(products.GetQuantitySold());
```

And then simply open the saved HTML file after saving it to the disk.

Is this okay for simple SQL reporting? Is there an better more common way? I want to avoid using any third party products or libraries.

Thanks

Comment: This will work fine, and if you are happy with it then no problem. Personally, I would use some sort of template approach. Have each HTML file as an actual file with the dynamic values as some unique merge field, then you can load the file, replace the merge fields and then save to disk. A unique field might look something like `{FIELD:QuantitySold}`

Comment: i'm curious, why you don't want to use third party libraries?

Answer (score 5):

This it totally acceptable, just like addings strings (`s += aValue`), but `StringBuilder` is much faster.

You could consider using HtmlTextWriter, see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmltextwriter.aspx

Last suggestion: You could have a file with template HTML stored on disc, with variables at some locations, like:

```
 <html><body>[GetQuantitySold]</body></html>
```

Then, load the file and replace the variables:

```
 string template = File.ReadAllText("MyTemplate.html");
 template = template.Replace("[GetQuantitySold"], products.GetQuantitySold().ToString());
```

Of course, for performance you can also use `StringBuilder` to replace the values.

Comment: I love the template idea. This is exactly what I needed and much simpler than things like T4. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is always the HTMLTextWriter, specifically created so you don't have to mangle in those tags yourself:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/system.web.ui.htmltextwriter.aspx

Answer (score 0):

This is acceptable.

Also have a look at AppendFormat

You can use it like below:

```
sb.AppendFormat("<li>{0} {1}</li>", person.FirstName, person.LastName);
```

besides you can also build HtmlControls, but that is another way. Like this:

```
HtmlGenericControl htmlcontrol = new HtmlGenericControl("li");
```

Choose what you prefer actually

Comment: and of course the html text writer, being said in another answer. This is also a good choice!

Answer (score 0):

In short, yes it's fine. However i would recommend using [HtmlTextWriter/StringWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmltextwriter.aspx) as it can generate html tags for you and allows you to programmtically control tag attributes etc...

Simple example: -

```
StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
using (HtmlTextWriter textWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWriter))
{
    //Begin list
    textWriter.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Ul);

    //List items
    textWriter.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Li);

    //Links 
    textWriter.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Href, "http://www.google.com");
    textWriter.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.A);
    textWriter.Write("Google");

    textWriter.RenderEndTag();//End A tag
    textWriter.RenderEndTag();//End Li tag

    //Render list end tag
    textWriter.RenderEndTag();
}
```